# Get contents of html tags from document

Tags: javascript, file, tags

The user can upload an html document to my site and it is saved in the variable `file`. I want to be able to extract information from the file, specifically by scanning the document for certain tags and saving the contents of the tag in `data`.

How come I am unable to extract the innerHTML from  `<DIV class="staticheaders">` which is from a sample html document that is saved to `file`.

```
    window.onload = function() {

    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');

    fileInput.addEventListener('change', 
        function(e) {

            var file = fileInput.files[0]; 

            var textType = /text.*/;

            if (file.type.match(textType)) {


                var data;


                data = file.getElementsByTagName('staticheaders')[0].innerHTML;


                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    fileDisplayArea.innerText = data; 
                }   
            } 

        }
    );

}
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()` is not `getElementsByClassName()`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by `PHPglue` you are using `getElementsByTagName` which retrieves all elements that match a particular tag `<input>`, `<div>`, `<span>` etc.

The function you are looking for is `getElementsByClassName` which will return all elements that contain a particular css class